# NTLM authentication fails after type 2 response

Tags: java, ntlm

I have a site with SSO, which is using NTLM authentication, which was working perfectly so far on XP and win 7 (32bit), but recently my company decided to use win 7 (64bit) computers as well. On these PCs, the handshake ends after type 2 message, and tomcat returns 401. I have no clue how to investigate, maybe someone here can give me some tips.

This is in the servlet's doPost method:

```
        try {
        // NTLM Handshake
        // 1: Client --> Server | GET ...
        // 2: Client <-- Server | 401 Unauthorized/WWW-Authenticate: NTLM

        String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (auth == null) {
            response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
            response.flushBuffer();
            return;
        }
        if (auth.startsWith("NTLM ")) {
            byte[] msg = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(auth
                    .substring(5));
            int off = 0, length, offset;

            // 3: Client --> Server | GET .../Authorization: NTLM
            // <base64-encoded type-1-message>
            if (msg[8] == 1) {
                // 4: Client <-- Server | 401 Unauthorized/WWW-Authenticate:
                // NTLM <base64-encoded type-2-message>
                byte z = 0;
                byte[] msg1 = { (byte) 'N', (byte) 'T', (byte) 'L',
                        (byte) 'M', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'P', z,
                        (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, (byte) 40, z, z, z,
                        (byte) 1, (byte) 130, z, z, z, (byte) 2, (byte) 2,
                        (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z };

                response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM "
                        + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1));
                //response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.flushBuffer();
                return;
            }
            // 5: Client --> Server | GET .../Authorization: NTLM
            // <base64-encoded type-3-message>
            else if (msg[8] == 3) {
                off = 30;

                length = msg[off + 17] * 256 + msg[off + 16];
                offset = msg[off + 19] * 256 + msg[off + 18];
                String remoteHost = new String(msg, offset, length);

                length = msg[off + 1] * 256 + msg[off];
                offset = msg[off + 3] * 256 + msg[off + 2];
                String domain = new String(msg, offset, length);

                for (int i = 0; i < domain.length(); i += 2)
                    loginDomain += domain.charAt(i);

                length = msg[off + 9] * 256 + msg[off + 8];
                offset = msg[off + 11] * 256 + msg[off + 10];
                String username = new String(msg, offset, length);

                for (int i = 0; i < username.length(); i += 2)
                    loginUser += username.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception se) {
        log.error(loginUser + ", NTLM handshake exception:", se);
    }
```

Comment: You say authenticate, but you're not really checking the password here...!?!  It seems like you really just want to get the username out of the NTLM message?

Comment: @EdwardThomson You do not need a password for NTLM auth. NTLM is a challenge/response protocol.

Comment: @MatthiasHerlitzius Yeah, but the client uses the password to form the challenge.  So the server should *actually look at the response* to do authentication, not just assume that because you got *some* response that it must be a valid one.  There is no authentication here.

Comment: @EdwardThomson you are right, the thing is that I simply want to get the username. Ntlm gives it to you in 3 steps, but on our win 7 64 bit PCs the process stops after the 2nd step, there is no 3rd request.

Comment: The above code is a massive security hole if you actually use the username supplied to do anything meaningful. Anyone can just build and submit an NTLM type 3 message with whatever username they want. There needs to be code that validates the type 3 message with the NETLOGON service of an AD domain controller. Otherwise, there's no authentication going on here. It's just a door with no lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a policy issue on the 64 bit PCs as NTLMv2 was forced. Solution is to disable these setting in security policy.

• Run "secpol.msc" This should bring up a window titled "Local Security Policy"

• Security Settings > Local Policies >Security Options > "Network Security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP based …"

There are two similar entries which begins like this, open and uncheck "Require NTLMv2 session security".

At least it turned out we are using NTLMv1. :|

Comment: Does this rises any security vulnerability?

Comment: Yes it does, there are more up-to-date solutions (like kerberos) for SSO, but if you have a complex to change web application that is using NTLM1, you might do a risk analysis whether it worth do enable NTLM1 or put effort into development. It is not as trivial to fake NTLM handshake, not many users will have the skills to do so. So don't use it for a finance solution, but you can use it for a site for eg. tennis court booking.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

Enable NTLM Extended Security using below code

```
byte[] msg1 = {
  (byte) 'N', (byte) 'T', (byte) 'L', (byte) 'M',
  (byte) 'S', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'P',
  z, (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, (byte) 40, z, z, z,
  (byte) 1, (byte) 130, **(byte) 8**, z, z, (byte) 2, (byte) 2,
  (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z 
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I had used code similar to the posters question to extract users username in a java webapp. It stopped working with machines running windows 10. Your change (using (byte)8 after the (byte)130) fixed the problem. Could you explain how on earth did you find out that solution ?

Comment: I'd been exploring why similar code to the OP that I had post wasn't working for some users and this resolved my issue too. As @user467257 says, it'd be nice to know how this solution came about and why it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to insist with JCIFS try these links to overcome the "Invalid parameter error" and "Failed to negotiate with a suitable domain controller for".
It works with NTLM but is not guaranteed to work with NTLMv2 more secure.

"Invalid parameter"
https://www.sysaid.com/Sysforums/posts/list/9065.page .

"Failed to negotiate with a suitable domain controller for"
https://lists.samba.org/archive/jcifs/2005-August/005312.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I just improved some of the spelling in your post. It's also best to include the relevant information from a website just in case it goes down rather than just posting the links. Could you edit your answer to include the relevant information?

Answer (score 0):

Most corporate network will have moved over to NTLMv2. We ran into this problem a while ago and have acquired Jespa from http://www.ioplex.com/. As long as you have a Servlet stack, it works just fine. If you're using a non-Java EE stack like Play, I'm not aware of a solution other than turning down support to NTLMv1.

Comment: I've checked Jespa back in time when I investigated the issue, but as you have to buy it it was not an option, my manager told me to find a free solution. :) Anyway most of the links lead to this solution, so I guess if someone is taking this NTLM seriously will end up once with it.